# Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<Nop.Services.Cms.IWidgetPlugin>

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I have compiled my nopcommerce solution, and I am now getting this error:

Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1 Nop.Services.Cms.IWidgetService.LoadActiveWidgetsByWidgetZone(System.String)'.

the code it breaks at is:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString Widget(this HtmlHelper helper, string widgetZone)
        {
            return helper.Action("WidgetsByZone", "Widget", new { widgetZone = widgetZone });
        }
```

What does this mean? The method it says isn't there is here:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult WidgetsByZone(string widgetZone)
        {
            //model
            var model = new List<RenderWidgetModel>();

            //var widgets = _widgetService.LoadActiveWidgetsByWidgetZone(widgetZone);
            var widgets = _widgetService.LoadActiveWidgetsByWidgetZone(widgetZone, _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
            foreach (var widget in widgets)
            {
                var widgetModel = new RenderWidgetModel();

                string actionName;
                string controllerName;
                RouteValueDictionary routeValues;
                widget.GetDisplayWidgetRoute(widgetZone, out actionName, out controllerName, out routeValues);
                widgetModel.ActionName = actionName;
                widgetModel.ControllerName = controllerName;
                widgetModel.RouteValues = routeValues;

                model.Add(widgetModel);
            }

            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

its also worth noting that a solution clean and build works and the code runs fine, if you stop then run again it breaks,

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: This would happen if you're running against the wrong DLL version.

Comment: @SLaks i have checked the DLL version and it is correct

Comment: @Jason added code to question

Comment: If a clean and build causes it to work fine then you are dealing with dependent dll's not making it to the output directory when you just do a regular build.

Comment: @Jason ok thanks, how do i fix it? delete all plugins DLLs in the presentation and recompile them?

Comment: Is the widget service one of your projects in your solution. If so, make sure your dependent project references are linked to that project in your solution. If it's not your project ensure the "Copy Local" setting is set on your dependent dll references.

Comment: the widetservice and iwidgetservice are both classes referenced in the Nop.Services project

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the missing method is identified as `LoadActiveWidgetsByWidgetZone` whereas the method you posted is named  `WidgetsByZone`.  Is `LoadActiveWidgetsByWidgetZone` actually defined?  Could you have changed the method name and then forgot to recompile an assembly that uses that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you normally have to do in such a case is to manually delete the following (through Windows Explorer):

1. Presentation\Nop.Web\bin
2. Presentation\Nop.Web\obj
3. Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins

Then do a rebuild in Visual Studio.

Comment: No problem friend. :)